# Reading XML and converting it to JSON Smartly

Tags: java, json, xml

I have code which does the formatting and convert the XML to JSON but it is vary big and lethargic. I need to pick some 50 elements out of XML and format JSON using these elements.so many part is repeating but with different elements.
Below is the code:-

```java
private String createBrokeredMessage(String payload) {
    String message = "";
    String Ver = "";
    String ID = "";
            |
            |   
    String Rec = "";
    String default1 = "[]";

    try {
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource src = new InputSource();
        src.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(payload));

        Document doc = builder.parse(src);
        NodeList n1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("Ver");
        if (n1.getLength() > 0) {
            Ver = n1.item(0).getTextContent();
            if(Ver == "") {
                Ver = default1;
            }
            else {
                Ver = "\""+Ver+"\"";
            }
        }

        NodeList n2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("ID");
        if (n2.getLength() > 0) {
            ID = n2.item(0).getTextContent();
            if(ID == "") {
                ID = default1;
            }
            else {
                ID = "\""+ID+"\"";
            }
        }
        //|
        //|
        //|
        //|
        //|
        //|

        NodeList n49 = doc.getElementsByTagName("Rec");
        if (n49.getLength() > 0) {
            Rec = n49.item(0).getTextContent();
            if(Rec == "") {
                Rec = default1;
            }
            else {
                Rec = "\""+Rec+"\"";
            }
        }

        message = "{\"Envelope\":{\"Ver\":"+Ver+",\"ID\":"+ID+-------------------",\"Rec\":"+Rec+"}]}";
        System.out.println("Created message with ID" + message);
    } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return message;
}
```

Example XML:-

```
<?xml Version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Envelope>
    <Ver>1.13</Ver>
    <ID>SAO</ID>
    <Rec>men</Rec>
    <TransactionID>0987714805168</TransactionID>
  </Envelope>
  <Code>124</Code>
  <City></City>
  <CompCodes>
    <CompCode>US</CompCode>
    <Vend>13</Vend>
  </CompCodes>
  <BankData>
    <Code>123</Code>
    <BankAcctNum>231</BankAcctNum>
  </BankData>
  <BankData>
    <Code>124</Code>
    <BankAcctNum>431</BankAcctNum>
  </BankData>
</Data>
```

Output JSON:-

```
{
   "Envelope": {
      "Ver": "1.13",
      "ID": "SAO",
      "Rec": "men",
      "TransactionID": "0987714805168"
   },
   "Code": "124",
   "City": [],
   "CompCodes": [{
      "CompCode": "US",
      "Vend": "13"
   }],
   "BankData": [
      {
         "Code": "123",
         "BankAcctNum": "231"
      },
      {
         "Code": "124",
         "BankAcctNum": "431"
      }
   ]
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please add example input xml and output json data

Comment: Hi @Ackdari, I have added the examples

Comment: Underscore-java library can convert xml to json. U.xmlToJson(xml) method will help.

Comment: Hi @ValentynKolesnikov,
I can not use extenal library..it has to be standard java library such as org.json.*

Comment: Hi @Sahilkhan. You may copy source codes to your project.

Answer (score 0):

We can convert XML to JSON array using org.json.XML class, this provides a static method, XML.toJSONObject() to convert XML to JSON array.

**Syntax**

**public static JSONObject toJSONObject(java.lang.String string) throws JSONException**

In the below example, converting XML to JSON array

```
   import org.json.*;
   public class ConvertXMLToJSONArrayTest {
   public static String xmlString= "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><root><test       attrib=\"jsontext1\">tutorialspoint</test><test attrib=\"jsontext2\">tutorix</test></root>";
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
       JSONObject json = XML.toJSONObject(xmlString); // converts xml to json
       String jsonPrettyPrintString = json.toString(4); // json pretty print
       System.out.println(jsonPrettyPrintString);
      } catch(JSONException je) {
         System.out.println(je.toString());
      }
    }
 }
```

In your case the code will be...

```
import org.json.*;
public class ConvertXMLToJSONArrayTest {
public static String xmlString= "<?xml Version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>" +
    "<Data xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">" +
    "<Envelope><Ver>1.13</Ver><ID>SAO</ID><Rec>men</Rec><TransactionID>0987714805168</TransactionID>"+
    "</Envelope><Code>124</Code><City></City><CompCodes><CompCode>US</CompCode><Vend>13</Vend></CompCodes>"+
    "<BankData><Code>123</Code><BankAcctNum>231</BankAcctNum></BankData><BankData><Code>124</Code><BankAcctNum>431</BankAcctNum>"+
    "</BankData></Data>";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
     JSONObject json = XML.toJSONObject(xmlString); // converts xml to json
     String jsonPrettyPrintString = json.toString(4); // json pretty print
     System.out.println(jsonPrettyPrintString);
  } catch(JSONException je) {
     System.out.println(je.toString());
  }
  }
 }
```

**Output :**

```
{"Data": {
"CompCodes": {
    "CompCode": "US",
    "Vend": 13
},
"BankData": [
    {
        "BankAcctNum": 231,
        "Code": 123
    },
    {
        "BankAcctNum": 431,
        "Code": 124
    }
],
"xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
"City": "",
"Envelope": {
    "Rec": "men",
    "Ver": 1.13,
    "ID": "SAO",
    "TransactionID": "0987714805168"
},
"Code": 124
}}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help!
But if you compare my desired output and your output, there are differences in the JSON
1) "Data" element should not be there.
2)"xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", should not be present.
3)empty element City is not there in the JSON
4)All the values should be in double quotes.

Comment: Hope it helps ... maybe some problem in my selection of jar file of json... you can try with other json jars from maven.....

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON Jackson to convert XML to JSON quick and easy.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String xml = "<?xml Version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>\n"
        + "<Data xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">\n"
        + "  <Envelope>\n"
        + "    <Ver>1.13</Ver>\n"
        + "    <ID>SAO</ID>\n"
        + "    <Rec>men</Rec>\n"
        + "    <TransactionID>0987714805168</TransactionID>\n"
        + "  </Envelope>\n"
        + "  <Code>124</Code>\n"
        + "  <City></City>\n"
        + "  <CompCodes>\n"
        + "    <CompCode>US</CompCode>\n"
        + "    <Vend>13</Vend>\n"
        + "  </CompCodes>\n"
        + "  <BankData>\n"
        + "    <Code>123</Code>\n"
        + "    <BankAcctNum>231</BankAcctNum>\n"
        + "  </BankData>\n"
        + "  <BankData>\n"
        + "    <Code>124</Code>\n"
        + "    <BankAcctNum>431</BankAcctNum>\n"
        + "  </BankData>\n"
        + "</Data>";

    JSONObject json = XML.toJSONObject(xml);
    System.out.println(json.toString());
}
```

Add the dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20200518</version>
</dependency>
```

See here: https://www.techiedelight.com/convert-xml-to-json-in-java/